# Appending elements to a numpy nd array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I have initialized a numpy nd array like the following

```
arr =  np.zeros((6, 6))
```

This empty array is passed as an input argument to a function,

```
def fun(arr):
    arr.append(1) # this works for arr = [] initialization
    return arr

for  i in range(0,12):
     fun(arr)
```

But append doesn't work for nd array. I want to fill up the elements of the nd array row-wise.
Is there any way to use a python scalar index for the nd array? I could increment this index every time `fun` is called and append elements to `arr`

Any suggestions?

Comment: `arr.append(1)` does **not** work for a 1D array. It's a thing *lists* support, not arrays.

Comment: Also, it sounds like you want to assign things to existing array cells, not make the array bigger like appending would.

Comment: `arr[0,:] = [1,4,2,5,6,4]`

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Yes, I have corrected. Append works when I initialize arr=[]. Yes, I don't want to make the array bigger

Comment: @hpaulj I want to append each entry row-wise. Each time the function `fun` is called it will generate only 1 entry that has to be stored in arr

Comment: Did you skip the the intro numpy docs?  `arr[0,:] = 23`.  Open an interactive python session and experiment

Comment: `append` is the wrong work.  `assign` or `set value` is better

Comment: `arr` has 36 slots, which currently are all 0.  You can assign a new value to each, or to various combinations.  But first you need to learn about array indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [523]: arr = np.zeros((6,6),int)                                                            
In [524]: arr                                                                                  
Out[524]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
In [525]: arr[0] = 1                                                                           
In [526]: arr                                                                                  
Out[526]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
In [527]: arr[1] = [1,2,3,4,5,6]                                                               
In [528]: arr[2,3:] = 2                                                                        
In [529]: arr                                                                                  
Out[529]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```